# Enabling 3D Touch Actions for Unsupported Devices with Long Press

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch, long-press

I want to enable Peek&Pop, and include 3D Touch actions for iPhone 6s & up users, however I also want to enable a long press to enter non-3D Touch users into the Action sheet.

I understand how to use the peek and pop delegate methods, and I understand how to create a long press gesture. What I need to know is how to connect the long press action to display the peek preview with actions showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all that I can find online and in documentation, I now believe that Apple does not allow you to show the 3D Touch UI on non-3D Touch devices. While the other answer here is a decent alternative (implementing a long press to do an action on non-3D Touch), there is no current answer to my original question.